# Beanshell assertion successfull message in Jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter, assertion, beanshell

Given below code snippet  i am using in beanshell assertion to verify the soap /json responses . if the both values (names) are not equals my bean shell assertion show failure message as given below(i could see the assertion failure in view result section) . I would like to display the successful  message if bean shell assertion pass or  condition pass ? Can anyone advise how to show the successful message in view result section?

```
String soap_firstName=vars.get("soap_firstName");
String json_firstName=vars.get("json_firstName");

    if(!soap_firstName.equals(json_firstName)){
     Failure=true;
     FailureMessage = "SOAP first name not match with Json first name ";

    } else{
         Failure=false;
       //TODO: send the result to assertion message section -> "SOAP and  Json first name are equal";

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In the beanshell assertion, you can update only below objects.

- Failure
- FailureMessage
- SampleResult
- vars
- props
- log

You can use either log object to log the messages or SampleResult to update the ResponseMessage.

`log.info("PASSED");`

Or

`SampleResult.setResponseMessage("PASSED");`

The result will look like this

[image]

**Follow up:**

We do not have any property to show a success message for the Assertion Results listener. It seems to make sense for me to show only a failure message when things do not go as expected. Otherwise, It is assumed that it is Success.

Comment: this is perfect, I have multiple bean shell assertion,if i add the message in SampleResult.setResponseMessage() method i could see the last assertion result only , is there any way to show the success message in Assertion Listener? I would like to show custom messages based on the assertion.

Comment: I have multiple bean shell assertion ,and i would like to show message like given below. 1.Name are equal 2. Age are equal 3.Country are equal ..Please advise.

Comment: @VasanthDha, We do not have any property to show a success message for the Assertion Results listener. It seems to make sense for me to show only a failure message when things do not go as expected. Otherwise, It is assumed that it is Success.